# What is the best data structure to lookup if something exists?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash, hashtable, lookup

I want to keep a list of things I've already encountered in my recursive looping so I can avoid recalculating the same things over and over again. What is the most efficient data structure for this?

Looking at complexity analysis, Hashtables seem to be the most efficient for lookups. However, it feels inefficient to hold a data structure of key value pairs when all I'm interested in is looking up whether a specified key exists.

I thought that maybe a set would be a good idea, but its complexity doesn't seem to indicate so.

Comment: There's no one best solution, we'd need more information, but hash tables are indeed used often for this. You don't need to store a value with the key if you're not using it. The efficiency of hash tables hinges on how good the hash function is and also how well you know the size of the population in advance.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what ***type*** of things you'd like to store?

Comment: There are hash tables that hold only the keys, and then there are those that hold keys and values. The former is usually called a set, or a hash set. The latter is typically called a map or a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set probably is the correct abstract data type for this, since really the only information it encodes is whether an item is inside or not.

Using a set doesn't specify a particular implementation though. In most contexts, you should be able to find a set type implemented using hashing, or some type of tree structure. Which one you choose would depend on if the data you're inserting can be efficiently hashed or ordered.

In some libraries you will find set types that are implemented using the library's map types, but where the value is ignored. For example in rust, the standard library's `HashSet` type is implemented using the `HashMap` type.